# unable to read pdf document using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, pdf

I am writing code to read pdf file in selenium using Java PDF Library.
I wrote my code as

```
    URL url = new URL(str);
    InputStream is=url.openStream();
    BufferedInputStream fileParse=new BufferedInputStream(is);
    PDDocument document=null;
    document=PDDocument.load(fileParse);
    String pdfContent=new PDFTextStripper().getText(document);
```

But I am getting error at line document=PDDocument.load(fileParse) along with

```
    java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1119)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:2017)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:1988)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:269)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1143)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1040)
```

I need to verify the content on the pdf file .
Appreciate the help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use below line of code and its working:

```
//Loading an existing document
 File file = new File("yourPdfFilepath");
 PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
 //Instantiate PDFTextStripper class
 PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
 //Retrieving text from PDF document
 String pdfcontent = pdfStripper.getText(document);
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you for the response. I need to read the opened page not the existing pdf document.